# How to make a menu with this effect in unity3d?

Tags: scroll, unity-game-engine, menu

Sorry, I'll try to explain better.

I want to make a sliding menu where you can select a character. I want the character that is at the center increases in size to know that this is the current character. The effect can be seen in the game of Crossy Road when you want to select a character.

Sorry but I can't upload a imagen because i am new in the forum

Comment: @MickyDuncan Sorry, I'll try to explain better.

I want to make a sliding menu where you can select a character.  I want the character that is at the center increases in size to know that this is the current character. The effect can be seen in the game of Crossy Road when you want to select a character.

Sorry but I can't upload a imagen because i am new in the forum.

Comment: Thanks Freddie.  You can improve your question above by popping what you just said into your question above by clicking **Edit** .  This will allow me to reverse the down-vote.  Thanks.  Wishing you well

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be able to help you without needing too much borrowed code. There are two possibilities here:

1. You have a perspective camera so the "selected" item can just be closer to the camera.
2. You have an orthographic camera so you will have to scale things.

For perspective:

```
List<GameObject> characters; //contains all character.
int selectedIndex = 0;      //index to the selected character.
float spacing = 10;         //space between chars

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("RightArrow"))
    {
        selectIndex++;
        ApplyChanges();
    }

     if(Input.GetKeyDown("LeftArrow"))
    {
        selectIndex--;
        ApplyChanges();
    } 
}

void ApllyChanges()
{
    // Make sure the selected index is within range and then space the characters.
    selectedIndex = selectedIndex % character.Count();
    SpaceCharacters();
}

void SpaceCharacters()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < characters.Count(); ++i)
    {
        // characters on the left will have a negative spacing and so will be placed to the left and vice versa for characters on the right.
        int offset = i - selectedIndex;

        characters[i].transform.position = new Vector3(offset * spacing, 0, 0);
    }
    // Move the selected character closer.
    characters[selectedIndex].transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,spacing);
}
```

For orthographic camera you will need to set the select characters transform.scale to a larger vector.

This won't animate anything or look cool. This code will just snap your characters into position.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I adopted was to attach objects to the transparent buttons in a scrool rect, so as to manage 3d objects with the convenient of scrool rect interface.

Here you can find the official documentation for use scrool rect: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ScrollRect.html

Maybe my assets can serve you ;)

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/60233